# How do I disable VSCode's output window from opening along with the terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

Having enjoyed VSCode's terminal (opening it via Ctrl+`) for a lot of programming adventures, the "OUTPUT" window has never been of much use and I always find myself closing it. I can't seem to find how to disable it from showing at all or at least not being expanded. Any solutions?
[image]

It actually seems that my view of the output panel is tied to the TERMINAL tab, which does have a dropdown with checks including a check next to "Output"! BUT... it is greyed out, and I don't see any related terminal/output config in settings
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of your layout but maybe you can simply right-click and then hide the output (and show or hide other terminal tabs such as "Azure", "Debug Console", "Problems" ...)

[image]

Comment: Great thought. I don't have OUTPUT in that main array of tabs though.


It actually seems that my view of the output panel is tied to the TERMINAL tab, which does have a dropdown with checks similar to yours with a check next to "Output"! BUT... it is greyed out hahaha. And I don't see any related terminal/output config in settings

Answer (score 0):

you can right click and click on set localization, that's what solved the problem for me.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34637370)

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on Output window (which is next to Terminal in Split View), there's an option called "Reset Location".

Upon clicking on this, Output will be moved to its original position.

[image]